# What is this insect found in Malaysia?

Tags: entomology

Found in Malaysia, South East Asia. Small insect with wingspan of around 1 centimetre. Its back legs and abdomen are pointed away from the wall.

Front View:
[image: Frontal view]

Diagonal View:
[image: Diagonal view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a moth, (Lepidoptera), in the family Pterophoridae. It looks very much like *Stenodacma wahlbergi*.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenodacma_wahlbergi